# best way to bind object array to checkbox in angular with preselected values

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have and list of checkbox. i have read many solutions online but its not getting clear to how to exactly handle this. i have implemented one way but it has multiple problems. one preselected values are not showing and function isSelected is being called multiple times.

HTML -

```
<div class="checkbox" ng-repeat="service in EditController.services">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="{{service.serviceId}}" ng-model="selection" 
            ng-checked="EditController.isSelected(service.serviceId)" 
            ng-change="onSelection(selection, service)"/>
        <span class="label">{{service.serviceValue}}</span>
    </label>
</div>
```

JS-

```
 onSelection(selection, service){
   var EditController = this;
   if(!EditController.selectedServices){
     EditController.selectedServices = [];
   }
   if(selection){
     EditController.selectedServices.push(service);
   }
 }

 isSelected(serviceId){
   var EditController = this;
   angular.forEach(EditController.editForm.services, function(value, index){
     if(value.serviceId === serviceId){
       return true;
     }
   });
   return false;
 }

 JSON : 

 editForm : 
{

  "services": [
    {
      "serviceId": "ESSL China",
      "serviceValue": "ESSL China"
    }
}
```

services :

```
{
  "serviceId": "ESSL China",
  "serviceValue": "ESSL China"
},
{
  "serviceId": "service1",
  "serviceValue": "service1"
}
```

this doesn't looks good. what could be the best way to handle such scenarios  in angularjs world.